# Canonical ensemble: Why do I lose dependency on the number of particles N here?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, partition-function

I have a problem understanding the solution of an exercise that deals with a gas in the framework of the canonical ensemble. Because I'm not a native english speaker some sentences might sound a bit weird.

The exercise:

A cylinder with infinite height is filled with an ideal classical gas. A homogenous gravitational field acts towards the cylinders axis of rotation. By using the canonical ensemble, calculate:

1. The average kinetic energy of a gas particle
2. The average potential energy of a gas particle.

The relevant part of the solution:

[image]

What you can see is the solution of 1) - the average kinetic energy  of a gas particle.
In case you are wondering why the power of p increases by 2 in the numerator and denominator, that is because the author uses spherical coordinates for the impulse space and thus you get the p^2 from the jacobian. The final result is < t > = 1.5*k*T btw.

**My question:
How can it be that you lose the dependency on the number of particles N?**

In the first line of  you have the differentials to the power of N. Why do we lose that in the next step?
I do understand that the spatial integrals cancel out but this can't be responsible for eliminating N.
In my opinion, the whole fraction should be raised to the power of N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hamiltonian ensures that each particle is independent of the other so $3N$-dimensional integral is actually the product of $N$ integrals of $3$-dimensions. Now since in the numerator differs from the denominator only in the $\textbf{p}_1$ integral the other integrals cancel off.

Comment: Thank you, got it!